# Navigation back click event in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React Native application. I am using navigation in my application. I want to do something when user presses back navigation i.e. moved to a back screen.

[image]

How can i get the click event of "blacked circle Frage" in the above image. I am working on IOS

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom header with

```
import { Header } from "native-base";
```

And add below code in your route file to disable default header.

```
navigationOptions: {
header: null
}
```

my custome header code for your reference

```
<Header style={styles.header}>
<View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
<TouchableOpacity
style={styles.iconButton}
onPress={() => { this.createNote(); this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') }}>
 <Icon name="arrow-back" size={28} color="#606060" />
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
<View style={{ flex: 8 }}></View>
<View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
<TouchableOpacity
style={styles.iconButton}
 onPress={() => { this.createNote(); this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') }}>
<Icon name="check" size={28} color="#606060" />
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
</Header>
```

reference link:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-base

Comment: i think you did not get the question

Comment: Do you have to do some event onclick on Frag text  right

Comment: yes, i want to handle the click event of this button

Answer (score 1):

It probably varies depending on the libraries you are using. I am using react-native-paper in Expo, which uses the headerLeft option in the Stack.Screen component. Here's a complete example - save it and then 'expo start'

```
import { Provider as PaperProvider, Text } from 'react-native-paper'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <NavigationContainer >
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Example"
            options={{
              title: 'Example',
              headerLeft: () => <Text>Custom left button</Text>,
            }}
            component={() => <Text>Example body text</Text>}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}` on `TouchableOpacity` if you are redirecting to the previous page

Also you can use `this.props.navigation.navigate('Any_Screen')` to move to other screens.

Also, I would like to suggest you to get familiar with [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler) to move back to previous page when hardware back button is pressed.

Comment: It does redirect to the previous page, this is how stackNavigation works, i just want to handle its click event

Answer (score 0):

check this screen there are mutiple example of handling click event

```
import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';

    class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {

        static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions, screenProps }) => {
            return {
                title: navigation.getParam('title', 'A Nested Details Screen'),
            };
        };

        render() {
            const { navigation } = this.props;
            const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
            const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

            return (
                <View style={styles.detailsScreen}>
                    <Text>Details Screen</Text>
                    <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
                    <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
                    <Button
                        title="Go to Details... again"
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Details')}
                    />
                    <Button
                        title="Go to Home"
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
                    />
                    <Button
                        title="Go back"
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.popToTop()}
                    />
                    <Button
                        title="Update the title"
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.setParams({ title: 'Updated!' })}
                    />
                    <Button
                        title="Modal"
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MyModal')}
                    />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        detailsScreen: { 
            flex: 1, 
            alignItems: "center", 
            justifyContent: "center" 
        }
    })

    export default DetailsScreen;
```

things you have asked in the comment section I could not find any exact answer for your question but you can take a look into this url how header buttons work

https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/simple-header-button-v3

hope this will work for you

```
 header: ({ goBack }) => ({
    left: ( <Icon name={'chevron-left'} onPress={ () => { goBack() } }  /> ),  
}),
```

you can also follow this page https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/779

Comment: I am not asking about simple button click, i am asking about navigation back button click

Comment: please check the link below my answer hope that's may help you.

Comment: I want that back arrow click event @anik islam Shojib

Answer (score 0):

add the  code

```
onClick={this.props.navigation.goBack()}
```

or use specif navigation replace go back to

```
 onClick={this.props.navigation.navigate('namepagespacific')}
```